# Create an empty .mdf file like what Visual Studio does with 'Add New item' menu

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

I need to create an empty .mdf file in my application. Every thread I have read - here and there - suggest you to create an empty database with 'CREATE DATABSE' statement then create tables, Views, etc. with some scripts, but this is not what I want, coz I just want to create an empty .mdf file. Then I will connect to it and run my own script. This can be achieved by 'AttachDbFilename' attribute in connection string and you can connect to the empty .mdf file very easily.

As far as I can see, only VS has the ability to create an empty .mdf file, so can anybody help me achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a MSSQL instance installed, where do you plan to "attach" the file, I wonder? It's not a file database, like FoxPro or MS Access, you need SQL Server installed if you are about to use the database file. And if you do have an instance, you can always issue `create database` to it, provided the user has sufficient permissions.

Comment: I have MSSQL installed. I use the following connection string , so you don't need to attach db to database:  'Data Source=MyInstance;AttachDbFilename=.\D:\myApp\\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";'.

Comment: So connect to your server instance and run this query: `select * from sys.databases;` before and after your program executed this connection string.

Comment: I re-pharesd my question to better reflect my I need. Please read my last paragraph again.